# Why is Flutter just_audio package returning different duration in Android and iOS for same audio source?

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I am using just_audio package in flutter project to play audio from url.In android the audioPlayer.setUrl() function returns correct duration but in iOS the duration is not same. That is if the audio has a duration of 1:50:10 I am getting 1:50:25 in iOS.
Why is this happening? Do I have to do something extra for iOS? Please help me.

Here is my code

```
AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
await _audioPlayer.setUrl(url).then((value) {
  print(value);
});
```

Please let me know if I should provide anything else to find the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you should report this as an issue in the just_audio github repo.

Comment: That would have to be the native behaviour of each platform. I would imagine each platform is estimating the duration in different ways, and it's having to estimate it because you're using an audio file format that doesn't directly encode the duration in it as metadata.

Comment: So is there a workaround @RyanHeise ?

Comment: I'm just guessing your situation. You haven't provided any further information with regards to my last guess about file types, so it's not really possible for me to help more, but if you don't want to share more details about your audio file format, I would suggest that you can still investigate this issue yourself on the basis of that hint.